# Use of generics in databinding and live data

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata

I use LiveData and databinding in my app to populate a recyclerview from the viewmodel.

The property holding the items is defined as

```
abstract val searchItems : LiveData<List<BindableItem<*>>>
```

However, databinding is stripping the type for the LiveData and generating an Object type live data, which fails to compile.

This is the generated code for the property above:

```
android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData searchViewModelSearchItems = null;
```

For other non-generics properties the type is retained, for instance

```
android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.feature.search.adapter.CarouselItem>> searchViewModelCarouselItems = null;
```

How can use generics with databinding?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to get the databinding compiler to accept a list of generics, but a workaround is to define the list to be of type `Any` and then cast to `List<BindableItem<*>>` in the binding adapter that adds the items to the recyclerview. Not ideal, but at least works.

In the viewmodel:

```
abstract val items: LiveData<List<Any>>
```

In the binding adapter:

```
fun setItems(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        items: List<Any>?,
        onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener?
) {
    val bindableItems = items as? List<BindableItem<*>>
    /* do other stuff */
}
```